# How to select a different data source instance using a Repository and Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, controller, repository, repository-pattern

I am using a repository that populates the data to be used and queried before a subset is returned to the caller. An example follows.

A controller has code like this:

```
public class DuckbillItemsController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IDuckbillItemRepository DuckbillItemsRepository = new DuckbillItemRepository();

    public IEnumerable<DuckbillItem> GetBatchOfDuckbillItemsByStartingID(string ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        return DuckbillItemsRepository.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
    }
}
```

The Repository populates the data store to be queried in its constructor:

```
private readonly List<DuckbillItem> DuckbillItems = new List<DuckbillItem>();

public DuckbillItemRepository()
{
    string id = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
            @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=NRBQNRotPS;Password=NRBQNRotPS;Data Source=C:\PlatypusWin\DATA\PlatypusDAT03.MDB;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\PlatypusWin\Data\NRBQ.mdw"))
        {
            . . .
            Add(new DuckbillItem
            {
                . . .
```

But different users will use different databases; IOW, the connection string should in some cases be PlatypusDAT03, as shown above, but in other cases PlatypusDAT01, PlatypusDAT02, etc.

So, the caller has to pass a value to indicate this, an int such as "1", "2", "3" etc.

But this has to be received in the Controller, by adding another argument to the GetBatchOfDuckbillItemsByStartingID() method, so that it's GetBatchOfDuckbillItemsByStartingID(int DBSpecifier, string ID, int CountToFetch),
which will then change the code in the client from this:

```
string uri = String.Format("http://platypi:28642/api/Duckbills/{0}/{1}", lastIdFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
```

...to this:

```
string uri = String.Format("http://platypi:28642/api/Duckbills/{0}/{1}/{2}", DBSpecifier, lastIdFetched, RECORDS_TO_FETCH);
```

Right? But if so, how do I alert my Controller to call an overloaded constructor based on which DB instance is desired? Do I need to change my Controller code to something like this:

```
public class DuckbillItemsController : ApiController
{
    static readonly IDuckbillItemRepository DuckbillItemsRepository1 = new DuckbillItemRepository(1);
    static readonly IDuckbillItemRepository DuckbillItemsRepository2 = new DuckbillItemRepository(2);
    static readonly IDuckbillItemRepository DuckbillItemsRepository3 = new DuckbillItemRepository(3);
. . .

    public IEnumerable<DuckbillItem> GetBatchOfDuckbillItemsByStartingID(int DBSpecifier, string ID, int CountToFetch)
    {
        if (DBSpecifier == 1)
        {
                return DuckbillItemsRepository1.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
        }
        else if (DBSpecifier == 2)
        {
                return DuckbillItemsRepository2.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
        }
        else if (DBSpecifier == 3)
        {
                return DuckbillItemsRepository3.Get(ID, CountToFetch);
        }
. . .
    }
}
```

...and a Repository constructor like this:

```
public DuckbillItemRepository(int DBSpecifier)
{
    string id = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        if (DBSpecifier == 1)
       {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=NRBQNRotPS;Password=NRBQNRotPS;Data Source=C:\PlatypusWin\DATA\PlatypusDAT01.MDB;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\PlatypusWin\Data\NRBQ.mdw"))
       }
       else if (DBSpecifier == 2)
       {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=NRBQNRotPS;Password=NRBQNRotPS;Data Source=C:\PlatypusWin\DATA\PlatypusDAT02.MDB;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\PlatypusWin\Data\NRBQ.mdw"))
       }
       else if (DBSpecifier == 3)
       {
            using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(
                @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=NRBQNRotPS;Password=NRBQNRotPS;Data Source=C:\PlatypusWin\DATA\PlatypusDAT03.MDB;Jet OLEDB:System database=C:\PlatypusWin\Data\NRBQ.mdw"))
       }
       . . .
```

? Surely not, but how can I attack this?

Note: I know that using MS Access is "considered harmful"; I have no control/say over that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases I would maintain a dictionary or list, indexed by DBSpecifier.  This would avoid all the if/elseif statements.  If the DBSpecifier can start with 0 then I'd use a List, otherwise if you want to micromanage the DBSpecifier value I'd use a Dictionary.

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, IDuckbillItemRepository> Repositories = new Dictionary<int, IDuckbillItemRepository> {
    { 1, new DuckbillItemRepository(1) },
    { 2, new DuckbillItemRepository(2) },
    { 3, new DuckbillItemRepository(3) }
};
```

And then use it like this:

```
return Repositories[DBSpecifier].Get(ID, CountToFetch);
```

Likewise in the repository implementation:

```
static readonly Dictionary<int, string> ConnectionStrings = new Dictionary<int, string> {
    { 1, "@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;...DAT01.MDB..." },
    { 2, "@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;...DAT02.MDB..." },
    { 3, "@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;...DAT03.MDB..." }
};
```

And use it like this:

```
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(Repositories[DBSpecifier]))
```

Alternatively, to avoid repetition, you could initialize the Dictionary items in a for loop in a static constructor.

You can also do error checking for invalid DBSpecifier values by using dictionary.ContainsKey(DBSpecifier).

If you wanted to get fancy, you could lazy-load your Repositories dictionary on demand by checking if the dictionary contains a key with the given DBSpecifier, and create and add a new Repository if it hasn't been added yet.